# Flex and mouse wheels

Tags: apache-flex, mouse, scrollwheel

Here is the application I need help with:  http://www.nypinball.com/inventory.php

The entire box at the top is a Flex application.  The box on the left with the list of pinball machines is a VBox.  As you can see, if you try to scroll with your mousewheel, it doesnt respond.  The reason this is shut off is because I found that if it's turned on, when you scroll up/down, the whole page goes with it.  So if you scroll down four or five times, the application goes out of sight.  I tried finding a solution to this when I programmed this last year but wasnt able to find any answers.  Does anyone know if there's a way to make Flex grab the focus of the mousewheel and not let the browser move as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is another solution [here](http://company.avatar-soft.ro/blog/?p=4)

Same solution but no need of a div, it test if the event appear on a swf object

Comment: I actually just discovered this today as well, and came back to post it.  Weird, huh? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well... you could **turn off scrolling altogether**...

```
<body onmousewheel="return false;">
```

Finding a solution to your original problem would be a nicer solution. I'm 100% sure that Flash can react to mouse wheel events without scrolling the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

This project may help: [GAE SWF Project](http://gaeswf.appspot.com/)

They have a flex [example](http://gaeswf.appspot.com/examples/initial/flex) that appears to scroll nicely. There is a mousewheel tab in their example.

Comment: Wow, didn't scroll nicely for me (in FF3).

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=145307)

it use a div who encapsulate the swf object and catch the mousewheel event and stop it

i've tested it and it's working